# @Async and strange transaction race condition

Tags: spring, jpa, asynchronous, transactions

I have some @Async method. As a parameter to this method I am passing some entity(Action) which has lazy-loaded User entity. I'm facing seldom problem, where I'm not able to access User role field(I can have just one role). I tried to resolve it by passing directly the User entity. Still sometimes it is not working. I guess it is because the entity is just proxy which sometimes get broken if something happens to underlying session/transaction.

I understand that transactions are not propagated to the @Async method. So how is it, that sometimes the User entity is initilized(has role) and sometimes not. I have tried to suspend the @Async method and let the main thread to finish so the transaction will be closed and I would consistently get an error. This did not happen.

How come?I am really suspicious of  @LastModifiedBy used on the entity, which propably do some magic there.

Anyway the solution is to make the @Async transactional, but I am kind of nervous that I am not able to simulate this error and thus verify later it has been properly fixed.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACTION")
public class Action {
 ...
 @LastModifiedBy
 @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name="modified_by_user_id")
 private User modifiedBy;
```

and the method

```
  @Async
  public void async(User modifiedBy) {
    modifiedBy.getRole(); //sometimes fails
```

Currently when passing directly the user I've got

```
 java.lang.InternalError: Marking a ResultSet inactive that we did not know was opened!
    ...
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:156) [hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:260) [hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:68) [hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at model.entity.User_$$_jvst33f_8.getRole(User_$$_jvst33f_8.java) [classes:]
    ...
```

Comment: You are passing a managed entity into another thread. The session is was associated to might have been closed. Instead you should refresh/reload the entity in your async method (or properly initialize it before you are handing it to the async method).

Comment: Actually I am not searching for solution. I can call Hibernate.initialize, call getRole() in the main thread, fix the transactionality. Which I did, I am reading again the User and I have made the `@Async` method  `@Transactional `. But I'd like to know how it is possible that it works(and seldom doesn't). I would really expect this to never work, not to work occasionally. I really would like to know what happens under the hood in order to be able to simulate this.

Comment: As stated it is al about timing. It might be that the session it was associated with has been closed (the `@Transactional` here won't help as the `@Async` method will run in its own transaction with its own session). As long as the session exists it might work, but if the thread that called the async method ended and transaction was finished the session has been closed and cleared. Leading to these errors. Those might generally not occur but at times might (if the thread pool is full, or cpu is busy or ... ).

Comment: I know, this is why I load the User again by just it's id in the `@Async` method. But I have put the debug breakpoint in both the main thread and the async.method. Finishing first the main thread I expected the async. thread to fail as the main transaction/session should be gone. But it never failed.

Comment: Debugging without the exact same settings (db, firewalls etc) is always flawed. It might be that the session locally stays open a bit longer, could be a timeout of the connection. Problem/issue is you should never share managed objects between threads as you will run into al sorts of "nice" issues, like this one.

Comment: I tried to debug some more. The code is not in transaction, but still the select works. But still there needs to be some connection opened or what. It is maybe connected with C3P0 (close to this [issue](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=960703&sid=277f4fa70bd96f78e65d4e94850f2ce2)). How can one program properly when there are so much magic going on in background.

Comment: Selects work without transaction (although there is always a transaction on the DB level!), updates etc. won't work. Also that isn't the problem the problem lies in the original session being closed. Multi threading issues are generally hard to debug and solve. I would suggest using HikariCP instead of C3P0 imho a better connection pool.